# tag resources azure python sdk - operation merge?

Tags: python, azure, tags, resources, azure-sdk-python

i am trying to figure out how can i tag resources with operation Merge like in PS.

example in powershell -

```
Update-AzTag -ResourceId $s.ResourceId -Tag $mergedTags -Operation Replace
```

my code in python -

```
    # Tag the resource groups.
    resource_group_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(resource_group_name=rg["Resource-group-name"],parameters=
    {'location': rg['location'], 
        'tags':tags_dict,
        'Operation': 'Merge'})
```

as you can see i am trying my luck to put 'operation' : 'merge' but it dosent work...
any help here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed it with this code.. and it worked PERFECT -
(you should work with "update_at_scope".

```
resource_group_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id=sub.subscription_id)


         body = {
             "operation" :  "Merge",
             "properties" : {
                 "tags" : 
                     tags_dict,
             }
         }

         resource_group_client.tags.update_at_scope(rg["Resource-id"] ,body)
```

Answer (score 0):

We don’t have an option as merging in python **create_or_update** function, have a look on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/resource-manager-python-resources-and-groups/manage-azure-resources-and-resource-groups-with-python/) on merging tags.

We can use ***resource_group_params.update(tags={'hello': 'world'})*** to update all the tags at once.
Below is the code about updating

```
resource_group_params = {'location':'westus'} #adding location tag to a variable to pass it in create_or_update function
resource_group_params.update(tags={'hello': 'world'}) # adding tags (This will remove all the previous tags and update with the one which we are passing currently
client.resource_groups.create_or_update('azure-sample-group', resource_group_params)
```

But the above code from documentation will remove all the previous tags and update with the one which we are passing currently.

Here our requirement is to append/merge tags, So I have created a python script where we can append tags to the old tag:

```
# Import the needed credential and management objects from the libraries.
from types import FunctionType
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
import os

from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2016_02_01 import operations

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "SUBSCRIPTION ID" #Add your subscription ID
resource_group = "RESOURCE_GRP_ID" #Add your resource group
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
resource_list = resource_client.resource_groups.list()
for resource in resource_list:
    if resource.name == resource_group:
        appendtags = resource.tags #gathering old tags
        newTags = {"Name1": "first"} #new tags
        appendtags.update(newTags) # adding my new tags to old ones
        print(appendtags) 
        resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(resource_group_name=resource_group, parameters= {"location": "westus2", "tags": appendtags})
```